# How to see list of files stored in a directory

Tags: android, file, directory

I have built an app that makes a folder in the storage of the device. Here is the code I'm using:

```
    File wDirectory = new File("/sdcard/W/");

wDirectory.mkdirs();

File outputFile = new File(wDirectory, filename);

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
```

Now I want to know how do I show files in a list view in this directory.

Comment: http://www.edumobile.org/android/creating-custom-file-explorer-dialog-in-android/

Comment: first learn about `listview` hope you can display it after learning.

Comment: thanks Hemantvc. That was quite helpful.

Answer (score 0):

paste your folder path....

```
File folder = new File("your/path");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
  if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
    System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
  } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
    System.out.println("Directory " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
  }
}
```